# how to resolve scalar last value needed in openACC

Tags: openacc

While compiling openacc code, i am getting following warnings
215, Scalar last value needed after loop for x at line 239
         Scalar last value needed after loop for y at line 239
         Scalar last value needed after loop for x at line 240
         Scalar last value needed after loop for y at line 240
         Scalar last value needed after loop for x at line 242
         Scalar last value needed after loop for y at line 242
         Scalar last value needed after loop for x at line 246,248
         Scalar last value needed after loop for y at line 248,252

Does such warnings makes program to run sequentially how to use lastvalue clause in OpenACC ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, these warnings can cause the code to be run sequentially (see the compiler feedback output from -Minfo=accel assuming you're using PGI).  By default, scalars are first private.  However, if the scalar's value is used outside the OpenACC compute region, the compiler can't automatically privatize the scalar since it doesn't know which value to use.

This can occur when the scalar variable is used after the compute region, for example

```
#pragma acc parallel loop 
for (int i=...
    x = <expr>
    ...
}
printf("Final X=%d\n",x);
```

You can work around this my putting "x" inside a private clause, but the value printed for "x" will remain unchanged from it's value before the loop.

Another scenario in which this can occur, is when updating a global scalar inside a compute region.  In this case, you would want to put the variable in a data clause (such as "copy") to have the variable be shared by all threads, and then use the OpenACC "atomic" directive when updating the value.

A third scenario is when a scalar is passed by address to a device subroutine.  In this case, the compiler must assume that other references are made the scalar.  While most likely you're not going to assign a global pointer to the scalar, it's possible and since the compiler does not have visibility into the subroutine, it must assume it.  To fix, add the scalar to an OpenACC "private" clause, or change the code to pass the scalar by value.  Note that by default Fortran passes arguments by address.  To pass by value, use the F2003 "value" attribute on the argument's declaration.

If you have a different scenario than what's listed above, please provide example code illustrating the problem.

Comment: Here,I have to use last updated value of x in latter part of code without loosing parallel execution of loop.If i go with first scenario,I can't use x's recent value.If I use second scenario,atomic does not let more than one iteration to write value to x at same time.Is there any data clause in openACC like "lastprivate" in openmp that preserves loop's parallel execution nature and let us to use updated value of variable ?

Comment: No, there isn't an equivalent to "lastprivate" in OpenACC.  It's my understanding that the OpenACC committee discussed it, but didn't have a compelling use case for it.  Though the standard is user driven so consider joining the OpenACC Users List and requesting this feature.  http://list.openacc.org/mailman/listinfo/openacc-users_list.openacc.org